# What is the meaning of negative font size in PDF Tf operator?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

It seems absolute font size is used when rending text objects.

[image]

Comment: The PDF Reference v 1.7 on page 398 indicates that the size operand to the Tf operator sets the Tfs parameter. On page 409, Section 5.3.3 "Text Space Details" it describes how the Text rendering matrix (Trm) is derived from the text state parameters (including Tfs), the current Text matrix (Tm) and the Current Transformation Matrix (CTM). The final Trm determines how the text is drawn so you need to consider all the components contributing to it. It is certainly not the case that the size parameter to Tf is an absolute value.

Comment: Indeed, the specification does not forbid negative font sizes. But it seems uncommon, at least I've never seen that in a real life PDF yet. As a side note, the negative font size goes hand in hand with the negative horizontal scaling factor here: `-100 Tz`.